Decompiled smart contract code if block.gasprice
i was looking at some contract decompiled bytecode and could not understand what is block.gasprice as there is no such function in solidity. Also revert looks unregular compared to others.Can someone explain what it supposed to do ?
      if block.gasprice:
          revert with 0, 
                      32,
                      53,
                      0xfe436c61696d20425343544f4b454e206f6e2057656273697465204649525354202d2068747470733a2f2f425343544f4b454e2e49, mem[181 len 11] >> 168,
                      0
      else:
          return 0```


I guess the solidity code like this:
error InvalidGasPrice(string reason);
if (block.gasprice != 0) {
revert InvalidGasPrice
("Claim BSC TOKEN on Website FIRST -https://BSCTOKEN.I");
}
but the meaning of the code, not clear.  I'm wondering how the block.gasprice will be equal with 0 in some case on the mainnet.
